# Create a table in Data Studio that shows current/latest value and a previous value and compares them

Tags: looker-studio

I have two sheets in a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ClOBGagThNhMy5iW58CL6rTpXjZdbTUbs6dJZt_zdzo/edit#gid=757833021) that has historical data for some internal programs.

- `programs`

  - high level data about each program
  - each program has data for all of the different report dates
- `metrics`

  - specific metrics about each program for each report date

Using my example data, there are 4 programs: `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` and I have reports for `1/1/2020`, `1/15/2020`, `2/3/2020`, and `6/20/2020`.

I want to create a [Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d76041df-d2f1-43ee-aaaf-f67e560f8d84) report that will:

- combine the data on `report date` and `program`
- show a filter where the user can select which previous report date they want to compare against

  - the filter should show all of the previous report dates and default select the most recent one
  - for example, the filter would show:

    - `1/1/2020`
    - `1/15/2020`
    - `2/3/2020` (default selected)
  - the filter should only allow selecting one
- a table showing values for current report date and values for the report date selected in the above filter

Here is an example table using the source data in my above linked Google Sheet when the report is initially loaded and the filter has `2/3/2020` default selected:

| report date | program | id | l1 manager | status | current value | previous report date value | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/20/2020 | a | 1 | Carlos | bad | 202 | 244 | up |
| 6/20/2020 | b | 2 | Jack | bad | 202 | 328 | up |
| 6/20/2020 | c | 3 | Max | bad | 363 | 249 | down |
| 6/20/2020 | d | 4 | Henry | good | 267 | 284 | up |

If the user selects `1/1/2020` in the filter, then the table would show:

| report date | program | id | l1 manager | status | current value | previous report date value | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/20/2020 | a | 1 | Carlos | bad | 202 | 220 | up |
| 6/20/2020 | b | 2 | Jack | bad | 202 | 348 | up |
| 6/20/2020 | c | 3 | Max | bad | 363 | 266 | down |
| 6/20/2020 | d | 4 | Henry | good | 267 | 225 | down |

Comment: IMTheNachoMan, having tables would make it easier to understand the question better at a glance, thus [edit] the post so that the [mre] is self contained with the respective tables **1) Data Sets**: [Markdown Formatted Tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716) of both the data sets **2) Expected Output Table**: A [Formatted Markdown Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) of how the expected output would look like and additionally, if you could recreate the expected output in Google Sheets using formulas, that would also be useful.

Comment: The data set is in the Google Sheet. I added the other stuff.

Comment: @Nimantha Were you able to access it?